# Need help modifying code for input validation and error message

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Need some help with my code. I'm trying to modify written code to ask a user for "yes" or "no" in order for the loop to continue. I'm supposed to use a prime read and a while loop to display an error message if the user inputs anything other than "yes" or "no".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  //declare local variables
  String endProgram = "no";
  boolean inputValid;

  while (endProgram.equals("no")) {
    resetVariables();
    number = getNumber();
    totalScores = getScores(totalScores, number, score, counter);
    averageScores = getAverage(totalScores, number, averageScores);
    printAverage(averageScores);
    do {
      System.out.println("Do you want to end the program? Please enter yes or no: ");
     input.next();
     if (input.hasNext("yes") || input.hasNext("no")) {
       endProgram = input.next();
     } else {
       System.out.println("That is an invalid input!");
     }
  }
  while (!(input.hasNext("yes")) || !(input.hasNext("no")));
 }
}
```

Comment: This is what i have so far but it's not working properly I'm trying to see what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hasNext` method call doesn't take any parameters.  Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()).

Therefore you should get the value of the input first:

```
String response = input.next();
```

And then test the response:

```
!response.equalsIgnoreCase('yes') || !response.equalsIgnoreCase('no')
```

You could put this test into a method as you are checking the same thing multiple times.

It may be easier to see the logic of your program by changing `endProgram` to a boolean.  Perhaps even rename it to `running`;

```
boolean running = true;
...
while (running) {
  ...
  String response;
  boolean validResponse = false;

  while (!validResponse) {
    System.out.println("Do you want to end the program? Please enter yes or no: ");
    response = input.next();
    running = isContinueResponse(response);
    validResponse = isValidResponse(response);

    if (!validResponse) System.out.println("That is an invalid input!");
  }
}
```